# start new Activity after data were received from webservice

Tags: android, android-asynctask, invoke

I have the following question:

In my activity, I invoke a webservice. As soon, as the data were received, I want so start the next Activity. As it is now, the Activity starts directly after I called my `AsyncTask`.

This is how it looks like:

```
new PositionRequest().execute(lineNr);
Intent intent = new Intent(this, DataTableCreater.class);
intent.putExtra("RequestData", detailList);
startActivity(intent);
```

`detailList` is an ArrayList, that gets it's data in the `onPostExecute()` of the `AsyncTask`.

I tried some `boolean finished=false;`, which gets true in the `onPostExecute()` and put the `startActivity` into a

```
while(!finished){
try{
 wait(500);
 }catch(Exception e){

}
```

loop, which is of course not even close to a good solution. End if the invoke fails, I'm stuck in an endless loop.

So how can I have my `startActivity()` wait, until all data got received? Because otherwise I get a `NullPointerException`, because of my `intent.getStringArrayExtra()` in theDataTableCreater activity.

I had a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13543105/finish-the-activity-after-receiving-response-from-server), but it was no help to me.

If you need any more code or information, please let me know in the comments and I will add them.

**EDIT 1**:

I forgot to add, that i need to start the activity outside of the AsyncTask, because I have a second thread running parallel. I need both to be finished, before I start the activity. Both take about equal time to finish, so I can't say, which one finishes first, and start the activity from the other AsyncTask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using this and it is working fine for me

```
private class Off extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> 
    {
        Context mContext;

        ProgressDialog pd;

        Off(Context context)
        {
            mContext = context; 
            pd = new ProgressDialog(mContext);

        } 
        protected void onPreExecute() 
        {
            pd.setTitle("Please Wait...");
            pd.setMessage("Loading ...");
            pd.setCancelable(false);
            pd.show();
        } 
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result)
        {
            if(result)
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, DataTableCreater.class);
                intent.putExtra("RequestData", detailList);
                startActivity(intent);  
            }

            if(pd.isShowing()) pd.dismiss();
        } 

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) 
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Hope this will help you

**As per your First edit:** 
I think you should use your preference. in preference you should put flag of both asynctask and then check value of both, if both are true then and then only you can start your activity

Answer (score 1):

Your code for starting new activity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, DataTableCreater.class);
intent.putExtra("RequestData", detailList);
startActivity(intent);
```

should be in `onPostExecute()` method of your AsyncTask

Comment: you are of course right. I forgot to add, that i need to start the activity outside of the AsyncTask, because I have a second thread running parallel. I need both to be finished, before I start the activity. Both take about equal time to finish, so I can't say, which one finishes first, and start the activity from the other AsyncTask. Sorry, I should have provided these info in the first place.